# LNK2001 linker error while linking google benchmark lib

Tags: c++, linker, lnk2001, google-benchmark

I have a problem with linking benchmark.lib in my project. I've built it as described [here](https://github.com/google/benchmark#installation). I've got sln file, compiled it (in release mode) and then created my own VS project. Linker can find my lib but it doesn't link it anyway (LNK2001). I added path to needed header files, path to lib in additional library directories and my library name in additional dependencies but it still doesn't work. I try to compile it in release mode.
My files tree:

[image: Files in my project]

Project properties (linker):
[image: additional dependencies]

[image: Additional library directories]

Logs:

```
1>mybenchmark.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl benchmark::internal::FunctionBenchmark::~FunctionBenchmark(void)" (__imp_??1FunctionBenchmark@internal@benchmark@@UEAA@XZ)
1>mybenchmark.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl benchmark::internal::FunctionBenchmark::FunctionBenchmark(char const *,void (__cdecl*)(class benchmark::State &))" (__imp_??0FunctionBenchmark@internal@benchmark@@QEAA@PEBDP6AXAEAVState@2@@Z@Z)
1>mybenchmark.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct benchmark::State::StateIterator __cdecl benchmark::State::end(void)" (__imp_?end@State@benchmark@@QEAA?AUStateIterator@12@XZ)
1>mybenchmark.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct benchmark::State::StateIterator __cdecl benchmark::State::begin(void)" (__imp_?begin@State@benchmark@@QEAA?AUStateIterator@12@XZ)
1>C:\Users\Paweł\source\repos\benchmarkTest\x64\Release\benchmarkTest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
```

And my source file with some exemplary benchmark (also from previously linked github repo):

```cpp
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

static void BM_StringCreation(benchmark::State& state) {
  for (auto _ : state)
    std::string empty_string;
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(BM_StringCreation);

// Define another benchmark
static void BM_StringCopy(benchmark::State& state) {
  std::string x = "hello";
  for (auto _ : state)
    std::string copy(x);
}
BENCHMARK(BM_StringCopy);

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 8):

This a bit late but I also ran into this issue when I tried to use google benchmark in visual studio.

What I had to do was to set BENCHMARK_STATIC_DEFINE in 'Properties' -> 'C/C++' -> 'Preprocessor' -> 'Preprocessor Definitions'.

[Preprocessor properties screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C5LG.png)

Hope this works for you

Answer (score 1):

D_Rai's answer got rid of almost all of the linker error messages that google benchmark was giving me in visual studio, but it left me with one more: LNK2001   unresolved external symbol __imp_SHGetValueA

in order to solve this, I had to link to Shlwapi.lib.

Here are my full links and includes, for reference:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "dependencies/benchmark/build/src/Release/benchmark.lib")
#pragma comment ( lib, "Shlwapi.lib" )
#include "dependencies/benchmark/include/benchmark/benchmark.h"
```